# Combine Two Angular Apps

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-bootstrap, angular-module, angular-config

I'm pretty new to Angular and I did some research about how to combine multiple Angular apps into one app. However most of what I found are about creating multiple projects in one Angular app, which miss the instructions on how I can configure the two very developed and deployed apps with different ng zones into a "project" under one app.

So now the two apps each has their own ng zone and AppModule, and I'm wondering what's a clean way to combine the two into one app. Is the best practice to create a new ng app, creating 2 projects, and then configure the two apps into the projects, or to wrap one of the 2 apps into the other? Thank you so much!

My search results are mostly about creating multiple projects from the beginning, but now I have these 2 developed apps I don't know how to "modularize" them

Comment: I believe what you're looking for is called module federation.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.